# UITableViewCell Align all subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, alignment

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which has some subviews. i.e. some labels, some images. I want all these subviews to be right aligned in the UITable. How do i do that?

I have tried these approaches -

1.In InterfaceBuilder when I select the UITableViewCell, I can set the "indentaion" section. It's by default 0, I made it 100 but I see no change in the device.

2.I have tried this in the code too. Override the default method...

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}
```

The above code also does not work. How do I align all my subviews in my `UITableViewCell` to right?

Basically, I want to display one cell left aligned (which is default) & some cells right aligned. As shown in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is automatic way everything will align to right. You will have to lay the view appropriately. For `UITextField` and `UILabel` objects you can set the `textAlignment` property to `UITextAlignmentRight`.

```
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
```

If necessary you must also adjust the `autoresizingMask` of the views to set it such that it has a `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin` mask set so that they stick to the right on view resize.

Comment: what about images? i mean UIImageView?

Comment: Aren't you using a custom cell for this? Are you trying to re-use one of the existing styles? In which case, you will have to calculate and set the frames yourselves. But the better option is to create a new cell.

Comment: yes I am using custom cells for this. But I have created a template cell in InterfaceBuilder i.e. I have a XIB which I import & fill in the labels & imagesViews. Now how do I align everything to the right?

Answer (score 0):

use interface builder for alignment.

Comment: how to do that? any tutorials on that?